# c# grab postdata and send to php

Tags: c#, php, http, output

okay so i have a c# script that works fine in debug mode and using other tools now i want to change part of the c# configuration currently this is the output line and sends it to another c# program called logs heres the line

```
    ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "loger.exe",buffer, NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

what i need to do is change this to send data to my php script via url

```
www.server.com/hitme.php
```

here is the php script i have made to handle the data

```
<?php
function db_connect()
{
$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'admin';
$db_password = 'admin';
$db_name = 'test';
$conn = @mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password) or die('Unable to connect DB.');
@mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn) or die('Unable to connect DB.');
}
function insertData($DATA)
{
db_connect();
$requete = "INSERT INTO data SET col_Data='".$DATA."'";
if(!mysql_query($requete))
echo mysql_error();
else
echo 'data accepted.';
}
if(isset($_GET['DATA']))
{
insertData($_GET['DATA']);
}
else
{
echo 'Nop';
}
?>
```

can anyone please help .....

Comment: May be `WebClient.DownloadString("www.server.com/hitme.php?DATA=blabla")`?

Comment: @mshsayem this did not work also what the blabla on the end

Comment: _blabla_ is the placeholder for _what-you-want-to-send_. Did you get a response like _'Nop'_ ?